# Why is the order of destruction same as order of construction, with static object (C++)?

Tags: c++, constructor, static, destructor

The code is :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() { cout << "A::A" << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "A::~" << endl; }
};

class B
{
public:
    B() { cout << "B::B" << endl; }
    ~B() { cout << "B::~" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    static A a;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
B::B
A::A
B::~
A::~
```

The scope of non-static object `b` and the scope of static object `a` ends at the end of `main()` function.

Question : Why is the order of constructors is same as the order of destructors ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Static local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) will be destroyed at program exit.

> The destructor for a block-scope static variable is called at program exit, but only if the initialization took place successfully.

So `b` will be destoryed firstly at the end of `main()`, `a` will be destroyed after that.

For the initialization,

> are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration

So `b` will be initialized firstly in `main()`, then `a` gets initialized.

Comment: Is the end of `main()` is same as program exit ??

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula No, after `main()` ends, there're still some stuffs needs to be done, like destroying objects with static storage duration, including `a` here.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula no, not really. Implementation defined, but main enters and exits way before run-time would do something. You get library and globals intializatin first, then after main() you get everything destroyed in certain complex (and not fully defined) order.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula When `main()` ends, only objects defined in `main()` with automatic storage duration are destroyed, including `b` here.

Answer (score 3):

Because they have different lifespans. `A` is declared as function-local static variable.

Object created by declaration of automatic function-local variable got lifespan which begins before any use of that object and ends with the most nested code block (braces block) containing that declaration. In your case that's function `main()` body.

Object created by declaration of static function-local variable begins to exist after execution flow had entered the most nested code block containing that declaration and before any use of that object.
It got process-wide life span (stops to exist at `std::atexit()`), which happens after the function `main()` will be exited.

SO they are created in this particular case in order of declaration, but `A` will get destroyed way later. If your function was called twice, you'd see that `B` would be created twice but `A` only once. If function's flow would somehow omit either declaration, by `if()` statement or by returning early, the order of their creation of would change or both may be omitted.

It's implementation specific detail, but usually destruction of function-local statics implemented in same way as destruction of global objects, by call to a library function  that lies under implementation of [std::atexit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit), adding the address of destructor bound with value of pointer to object itself, but the execution may be concurrent (or may be not) with result of user's calls of `std::atexit`.

Answer (score 0):

As addition to already existing answers, lets take a more phenomenological approach. Consider a small change on your example:

```
void foo() {
    B b;
    static A a;
}

int main() {
    foo();
    foo();
}
```

I assume you know that `a` is initialized only once and on the second call we get the exact same object `a`, because it is declared as `static`. Hence, it cannot be destroyed during or directly after the first call to `foo`. The expected first part of the output is

```
B::B    // first call to foo()
A::A
B::~
B::B    // second call to foo()
        // no second call to A::A !
B::~
```

`a` can only be destroyed when your program terminates, otherwise you could not "reuse" it when calling the function again (thats why I had to modify the example, you cannot call `main`). As other answers explain in great detail, this happens after `main` returns. Hence last line of output will be

```
 A::~
```